# Does the Magic Weapon spell, cast by a Mark of Making Human Barbarian, continue to function while Raging?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits, barbarian, rage

The Barbarian 1st level ability Rage states:

> If you are able to cast spells, you can’t cast them or **concentrate
> on them** while raging.

And the Variant Human: Mark of Making innate ability Spellsmith states:

> You know the *mending* cantrip. **You can also cast the *magic weapon*
> spell with this trait. When you do so, the spell lasts for 1 hour and
> doesn’t require concentration.** Once you cast the spell with this
> trait, you can’t do so again until you finish a long rest.
> Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

If I cast *magic weapon* first with Spellsmith, and then Rage, will it cancel *magic weapon* even though I don't have to concentrate on it?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 28):

### This version of *Magic Weapon* keeps functioning while you rage

Seems pretty straightforward. You cast the spell while you were allowed to do so, and since it doesn't require concentration, it keeps functioning while you rage. You have a specific rule that says your version of *magic weapon* doesn't require concentration, so it doesn't end because of an effect that solely affects spells that *do* require concentration.